Where can I find the reference to the Shraddha Mantra, where the priest offers sesame seed and water and utters "be content" (तृप्यत्याम्)?
Where can I find the reference to the Shraddha Mantra, where the priest (or maybe the son, not sure) offers sesame seed and water to the departed soul and utters "be content, be content and be content" (तृप्यत्वाम् - tṛpyatvam)?
This was mentioned by Sri Sri Ravishankar. He said that the significance of this ritual is to tell the departed soul to leave all his material desires as well as belongings as insignificant as mere sesame seeds and find contentment in his heart. This is nice. Want to know where to find the reference for this. My wild guess is either in Garuda or Vayu Purana or in the Pitrimedha Sutras or Shraddhakalpas or Grihyasutras.
